# Gdb not loading source file to be used at fork

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, fork

My main function forks and the child calls exec on a program i have compiled and linked. When either in gdb of vscode, I cannot put breakpoints on the files to be run with exec(). What can I do?

The funny thing is, it was working properly until some time ago. Now it just refuses to work.

Nothing changed is the point. It just suddenly stopped working from one debug session to the next. All I am asking is given your experience, what would most likely be the culprit in a situation like this?

Comment: STFW for undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Execl() needs a NULL as a last argument to function properly. I still do not understand why it worked just fine prior to me appending said argument, but it works now.

Comment: You might want to try adding `-Wall` to the flags passed to your compiler. Then you'd get messages such as `warning: missing sentinel in function call`.